# Elegant way to convert a tree to a Functional Graph Library tree?

Tags: haskell, graph

My question concerns the apparent awkwardness in converting a tree into its [Functional Graph Library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.4.2.4) representation, which requires explicitly referencing node names in order to insert further nodes/edges.

Specifically, I've recursively built a rose tree (currently a `Data.Tree.Tree a` from `containers`), and want to convert it to a `Gr a ()` to call various functions against it.  To do so, one can first walk the tree (with the supply monad or one of the FGL's state monad types like NodeMapM) and tag each node with an identifier:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Control.Monad.Supply
import Data.Graph.Inductive
import Data.Tree

tagTree :: Tree a -> Supply Int (Tree (a,Int))
tagTree (Node n xs) = do
  xs' <- sequence (map tagTree xs)
  s   <- supply
  return $ Node (n,s) xs'
```

and then `evalSupply (tagTree tree) [1..]`, then use something like

```
taggedTreeToGraph :: Tree (a,Int) -> Gr a ()
taggedTreeToGraph (Node (n,i) xs) =
  ([],i,n,map (((),) . snd . rootLabel) xs)
    & foldr graphUnion empty (map taggedTreeToGraph xs)
      where
        graphUnion = undefined -- see 'mergeTwoGraphs' in package 'gbu'
```

Of course, these two stages can be combined.

So, is this a good way to do this conversion?  Or is there a simpler way I'm missing, or an abstraction I should be using of the conversion of a (hopefully very generic) tree-like data structure  to an FGL tree?

Edit:  I guess the point of this question is that my original parser is only four lines long and uses very simple combinators like `liftA (flip Node [])`, but to change the returned representation seemingly requires the large code above, which is strange.

(I'd be happy to produce a `Gr a ()` directly from the parser (a simple applicative parser using Parsec) with monad transformers, provided that it required minimally invasive changes to the parser.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Writer` to collect the list of nodes and the list of edges to pass to `mkGraph`.  Using lists with `Writer` is not efficient, so I'm using `DList` instead, and converting back to lists at the end.

```
import Data.Tree
import Data.Graph.Inductive
import Data.DList (singleton, fromList, toList)
import Control.Monad.RWS
import Control.Arrow

treeToGraph :: Tree a -> Gr a ()
treeToGraph t = uncurry mkGraph . (toList *** toList) . snd $ evalRWS (go t) () [1..]
  where go (Node a ns) = do
          i <- state $ head &&& tail
          es <- forM ns $ go >=> \j -> return (i, j, ())
          tell (singleton (i, a), fromList es)
          return i
```